# Does White have any feasible way to break through this position?

Tags: analysis, endgame, theory, closed-position

I recently played as Black in a [1+0 blitz game on Lichess](https://lichess.org/z9OLB7Hw/black) in which the below position was reached.

```
[FEN ""]

1. e4 Nf6 2. Nc3 e6 3. d4 d5 4. e5g Nfd7 5. f4 Nb6 6. Nf3 Nc6 7. Bb5 Bd7 8. O-O g6 9. Bxc6 Bxc6 10. Ne2 Bg7 11. g4 Qe7 12. g5 a6 13. b3 Nd7 14. c4 b5 15. c5 Bb7 16. a4 c6 17. axb5 axb5 18. Rxa8+ Bxa8 19. b4 O-O 20. Be3 Qd8 21. Qc2 Qb8 22. Ra1 Bb7 23. h4 Qc7 24. Ng3 Ra8 25. Rxa8+ Bxa8 26. h5 Kf8 27. h6 Bh8 28. Kg2 Qa7 29. Qd2 Ke7 30. Kh3 Kd8
```

A lockdown position eventually ensued, and I offered a draw to my opponent, even though I theoretically could have won on time but I am a fair player, and they accepted.

The final position is one in which I see no foreseeable advance for either side. Black shouldn’t even think of making one, with a useless dark-squared bishop and an imprisoned light-square one. White has a knight pair, which could jump past Black lines, though it would be hard to do so. A good knight outpost is on a5. Their dark-square bishop is also useless. Therefore, White has an small advantage, but it would hard to due with dancing queens. If exchanged, then there is much less of a chance of an advance.

If the game was continued between two other people who were given infinite time, could White, in theory, ever commence a winning breakthrough into Black’s camp, or can Black hold a draw? Ignore the 50-move rule if you must.

Comment: I have been reluctant for a while about people asking on Chess.SE for analysis or opinion about their internet blitz games but I had yet to see someone posting their bullet game... I mean, at least the question is well formulated, but writing it must have been 5 or 10 times longer than the game itself !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any way for White to make progress. There are a few ways but all don't lead to anything:

1) Maneuvering a knight to f6. This just gives Black an opportunity to exchange his bad h8-bishop. After ...Bxf6 gxf6, Black puts his knight on f8 and plays ...Ke8, defending the f7- and h7- pawns.

2) Playing the f5 pawn sac. The purpose of this would be to plant a knight on f4. But here Black just plays ...exf5 and again employs ...Nf8, defending the e6- and g6- squares.

3) Putting a knight on a5. This doesn't really due much and hardly warrants a response from Black.

I also let Stockfish think to depth 68. The evaluation it gave is 1.97, which sounds bad, except it gave this same evaluation before it reached depth 30. This suggests White has no way to make any progress, meaning most likely the result is a draw (though it doesn't prove it).

Btw, in a 1+0 game trying to flag your opponent in a dead drawn position is completely fine. Aiming to win on time in bullet is a huge part of that time control. I'd only considering playing on there an unfair practice maybe in longer time controls (say over 5+0).

Comment: +1 this is the kind of position in which Stockfish will happily evaluate at +1.97 for 30 moves and then as the 50-move rule helps it prune, realize that it's actually a 0.00 position. I doubt the game will actually end like this - there'll be some exchanges - but I'd take it as a "drawn until proven otherwise" position/.

Comment: @Allure Agreed. The 50-move rule helping it prune is a good point, since even though it thought to depth 68 this only means 68 ply = 32 moves.

Comment: A possible alternative plan for White is to reorganize with Na5, Nc3, Qd3, and then look for an opportunity to sack a knight for two passed pawns with either Nxc6 or Nxb5. Black can easily parry it, e.g. with Nb8, Ba6 and Qb7.

Comment: @Evargalo Good point, didn't think of that. But yes Black should be able to defend easily.

Answer (score 1):

White has a possible way to break in.  Just one way.
But there is a   risk that white might lose if he does that.

but the b on h8 is dead so it really does not cost that much to try.

I have not analysed in depth so you run through an engine if you care.

horsies on a3 and c3,   bishop on b2 or c1  and Q on d3 or e2 or f1.

and it looks like q on e2  and the b on c1   would be the easiest with the other moves needed.

would have to do this subtly so black does not move his horsie to c7 which will take 3 moves and then guard the b5 pawn with the queen taking one more move.  maybe start with q b2  and a horsie to a3
then move the b to look like you are blocking the q from the a file.
move white q to its square then maneuver the other horsie into position.

white will have to act dumb and do funny maneuvers to get to the point where he move for the break before black is ready.  no guarantees but it could happen.

finally
sac a horsie for the pawn on b5
win a second pawn
advance pawns on band c files